How to get the last scheduled fire time for a Quartz job's daily cycle?
I'm using Quartz (v2.3.2) for scheduling a process in a Spring Boot application, and I need help identifying the exact end time for the current daily cycle. Here’s the setup:
The job is scheduled to run every 5 minutes from 7:00 PM to 2:59 AM the next day. I want to retrieve the end time of this cycle, specifically 2:59 AM on the corresponding day, so I can recognize when this cycle finishes before the next one starts at 7:00 PM.
I'm familiar with methods like getNextFireTime() and getPreviousFireTime(), but they don’t seem to provide the final fire time within a specific daily window. Is there a way to get the last fire time of the current cycle based on this daily schedule?
Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this with Quartz would be much appreciated. Thanks!
I have tried to extract the end time from splitting the cron expression string but later realized that's not the right solution.

Looks like similar questions 
Finding Last Fired time using a Cron Expression in Java
Fetch the "Last Ran At" time for a quartz job
I referred triggers documentation on quartz https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-4.x/tutorial/more-about-triggers.html
What we can best do is fetch the trigger
and based on the fact that "The job is scheduled to run every 5 minutes from 7:00 PM to 2:59 AM the next day. I want to retrieve the end time of this cycle, specifically 2:59 AM on the corresponding day, so I can recognize when this cycle finishes before the next one starts at 7:00 PM."
And loop through using getFireTimeAfter to find the last fire time within this range.
Check if the below works for you.
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.start();

TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey("yourTriggerName", "yourTriggerGroup");
 Trigger trigger = scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey);

// Define the start and end time for today
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String todayStr = dateFormat.format(new Date());
Date startOfCycle = dateFormat.parse(todayStr + " 19:00:00");
Date endOfCycle = dateFormat.parse(todayStr + " 02:59:00");
        
// If the endOfCycle is before the startOfCycle, it means it's on the next day
if (endOfCycle.before(startOfCycle)) {
    endOfCycle = new Date(endOfCycle.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}

Date nextFireTime = trigger.getFireTimeAfter(startOfCycle);
Date lastFireTime = null;

while (nextFireTime != null && nextFireTime.before(endOfCycle)) {
    lastFireTime = nextFireTime;
    nextFireTime = trigger.getFireTimeAfter(nextFireTime);
}

System.out.println("Last fire time in the current cycle: " + lastFireTime);


Thanks for the answer, Sharad Paul. It has helped me make progress. In my case, I only have the cron expression and trigger, and the values for startOfCycle and endOfCycle will always be dynamic. The issue I’m facing is that I’m not sure how to get the endOfCycle value. Is there a way to obtain that from the trigger? For now i have managed to get the hour my splitting the cron using spaces.
